# AWS S3 bucket - Allow download files to every IAM and Users from specific AWS Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policyd

Look for a policy for S3 bucket that will allow all IAM roles and users from different account, to be able to download files from the bucket that is located in my AWS account.

Thanks for help

Comment: Just a note as it's note quite what you've asked, but allowing a specific role from another account to access a bucket is more difficult. You have to get the role's aws:userid using "aws iam get-role" then use that userid in the bucket policy. It's documented here but it takes some time to get your head around it https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/

Answer (score 0):

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Sid": "Example permissions",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB-ID:root"
         },
         "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucket"
         ],
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Directly from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html).

Comment: You may need to add "s3:GetObject" permissions as well.

Comment: And remember that "s3:GetObject" needs to target the path resource e.g. "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*", not just "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1". This often catches me out when I get an Access Denied